# How to skip tests when debugging test with Intellij which installs the package before debugging

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I have a maven project where I'd like to debug tests using IntelliJ. The problem is that when I select the test I'd like to debug IntelliJ **first** executes `mvn install` command in order to be able to execute tests against the most recent code, and **after this** executes the test and allow me to debug.

I have multiple problems with this:

- the project contains hundreds of tests which takes 2-3 minutes to execute them. It is super slow especially when I need to restart debugging frequently
- if my test compiles, but still fails I can't start debugging since it will fail the `maven install` part of the execution and IntelliJ doesn't kick off debugging
- I haven't found any hints in IntelliJ's doc about how to manipulate the `mvn install` part of the debugging process
- yes, I could start maven in debug mode in the command line and attach IntelliJ to it, but that process is very fragile and it is 2021... let me use the IntelliJ fully...

I tried to add a `Before launch` step like `mvn clean install -Dmaven.test.skip=true`, but it results that the test classes won't be compiled.

My question is how can I manipulate the whole Debugging process is IntelliJ, especially the `maven install` part? What is the good solution here?

I'm using TestNG and the user interface doesn't offer me any option to do manipulate mvn install part.

Comment: -DskipTests should be sufficient

Comment: Hmmm... I should have tried out that one too and realize that it just works. Thanks for the help!